# connect mySQL with Nodejs

Tags: mysql, windows, node.js, npm

i am trying to install mysql Driver for Node.js 
but i am getting below error .

can some one will help me ?

Thanks in Advance :)

C:\tmp\node>npm install mysql

```
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/mysql
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/mysql
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/mysql
npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settin
gs.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 5.1.2600
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "mysql"
npm ERR! cwd C:\tmp\node
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.5`enter code here`
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\tmp\node\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: Did you check `C:\tmp\node\npm-debug.log` to see if there's more information?

Answer (score 0):

Error is not strictly connected to mysql module.
Probably you are behind the proxy, try to follow the instruction how to setup npm behind the proxy here:

http://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy